# Cortado Ogg-player in MediaElement.js - almost working

Tags: javascript, dom, mediaelement.js, ogg, cortado

I made a few changes to the MEjs demo player, to enable playback of OGG in IE/Safari browsers, using the Cortado Java applet.

I have play/pause working, and although getPlayPosition() isn't getting the current position in milliseconds as described in the [documentation](http://git.xiph.org/?p=cortado.git;a=blob;f=README), `applet.currentTime` and `applet.duration` work well for this purpose.

I thought it would be simple to hook these up to the current position indicators on the mejs player, but I'm running into a problem. `setCurrentTime` on the object is causing `DOM Exception: InVALID_STATE_ERR (11)` in IE, and a similar error happens in Safari. Apparently the object I'm trying to set no longer exists?

The code below will play and pause, and even give the seconds/total in the console (F12 tools MUST be enabled in IE.) Is there a good way to connect this to the play bar?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>HTML5 MediaElement</title>   

    <script src="../build/jquery.js"></script>  
    <script src="../build/mediaelement-and-player.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../build/mediaelementplayer.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>MediaElementPlayer.js</h1>

<p>Audio player</p>

<h2>OGG Player</h2>
<audio id="player2" src="http://www.archive.org/download/memoirs_holmes_0709_librivox/holmesmemoirs02doyle.ogg" type="" controls="controls">        
</audio>

<script>
MediaElementPlayer.prototype.buildplaypauseOrig = 
MediaElementPlayer.prototype.buildplaypause;
MediaElementPlayer.prototype.buildplaypause = function(a,b,c,d) {
    if (d.src.indexOf('.ogg') !=-1 /* && IE or safari */) {
        if (jQuery(this.$node).find('applet').length==0) {
            jQuery(this.$node).append('<applet code="com.fluendo.player.Cortado.class" codebase="http://theora.org/" archive="cortado.jar" width="100" height="100">'+
            '<param name="url" value="'+d.src+'"/><param name="seekable" value="true"/><param name="autoPlay", value="false"/></applet>');
        }
        var el = this.$node; //mejs audio element
        var initonload = function() {
            if (el.find('applet')[0].isActive) {
                var applet = el.find('applet')[0];
                // This is where it fails: mejs.players[0].setCurrentTime or d.setCurrentTime cause dom exception
                console.log(applet.code);
                        console.log(applet.currentTime);
                /*mejs.players[0]*/ //d.setCurrentTime(applet.currentTime);
                console.log(applet.duration);
                /*mejs.players[0]*/ //d.media.duration = applet.duration;
            } else {
                window.setTimeout(initonload,100);
            }
        }
        d.addEventListener("play",function() {
            var audio = el.attr('src');
            window.setInterval(function() {
                //try {
                var applet = el.find('applet')[0];
                console.log(applet.currentTime);
                // This is where it fails: mejs.players[0].setCurrentTime or d.setCurrentTime cause dom exception
                //mejs.players[0].setCurrentTime(applet.currentTime);
                console.log(applet.duration);
                /*mejs.players[0]*/ //d.media.duration = applet.duration;

                //}catch(e) {console.log(e)}
                //console.log(applet.getPlayPosition()+"ms");
            },1000);
            //jQuery(this).find('applet')[0].setParam('url',audio);
            el.find('applet')[0].doPlay();
        });
        d.addEventListener("pause",function() {
            var applet = el.find('applet')[0];
            applet.doPause();
        });
        d.addEventListener("load",function(e) {
            alert('load');
        });
    }
    this.buildplaypauseOrig(a,b,c,d);
}

mejs.HtmlMediaElementShim.determinePlaybackOrig = 
mejs.HtmlMediaElementShim.determinePlayback
mejs.HtmlMediaElementShim.determinePlayback = function(htmlMediaElement, options, supportsMediaTag, isMediaTag, src) {
    var res = this.determinePlaybackOrig(htmlMediaElement, options, supportsMediaTag, isMediaTag, src);
    //if (mejs.MediaFeatures.isIE) {
        res.method = 'native';
    //}
    return res;
}

$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is using MeJS 2.10.3.

Answer (score -1):

**[EDIT]**
After inspecting the [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) code, it seems that `mejs.players` is not an array, but an object, and in order to access the first player, you would have to look into `mejs.players['mep_0']`, since `mejs.players[0]` would be `undefined`.

---

My guess would be that jQuery fails to create an interactive `<applet>` element, since, from my experience, jQuery (which heavily relies on `document.createDocumentFragment`) sometimes fails to attach/trigger events on dynamically created/cloned DOM nodes, especially in IE, which could be the cause for this DOM error that you're seeing, because your `<applet>` object probably failed to initialize.

To try and fix this problem, I'd suggest to use the native `document.createElement` and `document.appendChild` methods instead of the `jQuery.append`.

```
if (jQuery(this.$node).find('applet').length==0) {
    var createElem = function(name, attributes) {
        var el = document.createElement(name);
        attributes = attributes || {};
        for (var a in attributes) {
            el.setAttribute(a, attributes[a]);
        }
        return el;
    };
    var applet = createElem('applet',{
        code:'com.fluendo.player.Cortado.class',
        codebase: 'http://theora.org/',
        archive: 'cortado.jar',
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    });
    applet.appendChild(createElem('param', {name:'url', value:d.src}));
    applet.appendChild(createElem('param', {name:'seekable', value: 'true'}));
    applet.appendChild(createElem('param', {name:'autoPlay', value: 'false'}));
    this.$node.get(0).appendChild(applet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it *does* create the applet element, playing and pausing works, console.log-ing the time works, but calling `mejs.players[0].setCurrentTime(applet.currentTime);` fails.

Comment: After inspecting the [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) code, it seems that `mejs.players` does not to be an array, but an object. To find the first player, you would have to look into `mejs.players['mep_0']`. `mejs.players[0]` would be undefined.

Comment: I noticed that when I tried this again with the latest ME.js, but this works with the older version I had started awhile ago.